# How can I stop Vercel preview deployments from appearing on pull requests?

Tags: github, vercel

I use Vercel to deploy a Next.js app and I use [Vercel for GitHub](https://vercel.com/docs/git/vercel-for-github) for CI/CD. Vercel automatically deploys code pushed to my `master` branch to production, and I would like to keep this functionality. However, Vercel also creates [preview deployments](https://vercel.com/docs/platform/deployments#preview) for [each push](https://vercel.com/docs/platform/deployments#preview), and when I create a pull request, this deployment shows up under 'Checks.' Is there a way to stop this from happening? I don't have an issue with Vercel creating a preview deployment for each push I make, but I would like for Vercel's deployment not to appear under the 'Checks' section of each pull request.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the "Ignore Build Step": https://vercel.com/support/articles/how-do-i-use-the-ignored-build-step-field-on-vercel

You can tell Vercel only to build `master` (or `main` depending on your `git` configuration), and all other branches will be ignored.

EDIT: Thanks to @Dani Akash for the suggestion below

Comment: The second comment on this page shows exactly how to do this.

Comment: Agree.  The second comment is super helpful.  Perhaps @paulogdm could update the article with example implementations including the `[ "$VERCEL_ENV" != production ]` solution.  Yes?

Comment: Absolutely! Doing now. Amazing addition indeed.

Answer (score 34):

Adding the following command in the ignored build step box of `/settings/git` page of your project to disable running the builds for non-production environments. Effectively disabling deploy previews

```
[ "$VERCEL_ENV" != production ]
```

[image]

Comment: https://vercel.com/docs/projects/overview#ignored-build-step, looks like there is a dedicated `Only build production` option now

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, if you have also have a staging branch and you want builds to be run for both main and staging you can you the following command:

```
[[ "$VERCEL_GIT_COMMIT_REF" != "staging" && "$VERCEL_GIT_COMMIT_REF" != "main"  ]]
```

You can also use a add ignored build step script in the root of your project. You can read more about it here: https://vercel.com/guides/how-do-i-use-the-ignored-build-step-field-on-vercel

Comment: Actually if you want to run on `staging` or `main` only, it should be like this
`[[ "$VERCEL_GIT_COMMIT_REF" == "staging" || "$VERCEL_GIT_COMMIT_REF" == "main"  ]]`

Comment: @HaiNguyen These are logically equivalent.