# How to prevent Vercel preview builds?

Tags: vercel

How to prevent preview builds other than production branch in Vercel?

I am wondering how to prevent builds other than the production branch because I am getting too many builds in one push because I am using monorepo.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I stop Vercel preview deployments from appearing on pull requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68232548/how-can-i-stop-vercel-preview-deployments-from-appearing-on-pull-requests)